# Best way to install psycopg2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am having trouble installing a Django app ([Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org)) on Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed most necessities using apt-get (except for django-compressor and south -used pip), including psycopg2 for Postgres. However when I go to run python manage.py createdb it gives this error:

```
Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

This is the command I'm using to install psycopg2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use pip to install psycopg2. I went to the website and it recommends installing through your OS package manager instead of pip.

I am working in a virtualenv except for when I am installing the psycopg2 elements....

Comment: Try running an `apt-get update` before the install.

Comment: I typically install psycopg2 via pip in a virtualenv. You may need to run: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev` first. If you've installed psycopg2 via apt, your virtualenv won't see it unless you've enabled the system-wide site packages for that env.

Comment: @Joseph, I've ran apt-get update multiple times, same error

Comment: @Brandon, I've ran that command, same error.  How do I enable the system-wide packages for the virtualenv?  Would it better just to use pip to install all the req's for Django/Mezzanine?

Comment: If you're using virutalenvwrapper, it's as simple as: `$ toggleglobalsitepackages` I haven't used Mezzanine, so I'm not sure if just running it's requirements.txt would make any difference.

Comment: @Brandon, ok thx. Mezzanine is great, should take a look!

Comment: I will. I usually use Django-CMS, but I'm not a fan of it's decision to do all front-end editing now.

Comment: I'm actually curious which website recommended to install the package using the system's package manager. Can you shed some light?

Comment: @Claudio, http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html came up as first result after Google search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `psycopg` you installed through `apt-get` is not visible from inside the virtual env.

You should install it through pip

```
pip install psycopg2
```

after sourcing your environment.

Answer (score 21):

If you need psycopg2 for a system installed program, then install it with the system package manager.  If you need it for a program in a virtualenv, install it in that virtualenv.

```
. env/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2
```

Note that on many distros, the development headers needed for compiling against libraries are not installed by default.  For psycopg2 on Ubuntu you'll need the python and postgresql headers.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libpq-dev
```

---

psycopg 2.7 now issues a warning that it will stop providing binary releases due to compatibility issues.

> The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.

See the [release announcement](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2018/02/08/psycopg-274-released/) for a thorough explanation. To handle the warning, tell pip not to download the pre-built wheel for psycopg2.

```
pip install --no-binary psycopg2 psycopg2
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, to resolve this issue on Ubuntu 14.04 with `virtualenv` I had to

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

then I could run

```
pip install psycopg2
```